# Incorrect sort with collection in java if unicode in the list

Tags: java, selenium, collections

I am trying to sort the list with different data in the list, such as unicode in the data or also english names but doesnot unable to sort because collection not able to understand the value as unicode.

Here is the code

```
public void sortingAscending(int indexColumn, String sortType) {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(progressBar)));

        ArrayList<String> obtainedList = new ArrayList<>();

        WebElement element = null;
        for (int index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[" + index + "]/td[" + indexColumn + "]"));
            obtainedList.add(element.getText());
            log.info("Adding first row element to array list " + element.getText());
        }
            ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String s : obtainedList) {
                sortedList.add(s);
                log.info("Sorting list " + s);
            }
                switch (sortType) {
                    case "Ascending":
                        Collections.sort(sortedList);
                        log.info("Ascending order " + sortedList);
                        break;
                    case "Descending":
                        Collections.sort(obtainedList,Collections.reverseOrder());
                        log.info("Descending order " + sortedList);
                        Assert.assertEquals(obtainedList, sortedList);
                        break;
                    default:
                        log.info("Default sort");
                }
    }
```

Here is the log data I can share with you for further understanding.

```
INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list 地区地区地区地区
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list 地区
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list Zentry, LLC
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list wqeew
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list WOOLWICH HISTORICAL SOCIETY INC
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list Wendy's Hot pizza
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list Vonage地区
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list Vivid Seats
 INFO [main] (CF.java:489)- Adding first row element to array list Vivid Seats
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list 地区地区地区地区
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list 地区
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list Zentry, LLC
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list wqeew
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list WOOLWICH HISTORICAL SOCIETY INC
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list Wendy's Hot pizza
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list Vonage地区
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list Vivid Seats
 INFO [main] (CF.java:494)- Sorting list Vivid Seats
 INFO [main] (CF.java:503)- Descending order [地区地区地区地区, 地区, Zentry, LLC, wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww, wqeew, WOOLWICH HISTORICAL SOCIETY INC, Wendy's Hot pizza, Vonage地区, Vivid Seats, Vivid Seats]
 INFO [main] (Hooks.java:116)- Jarvis Closed

java.lang.AssertionError: Lists differ at element [2]: Zentry, LLC != wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww expected [Zentry, LLC] but found [wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww]
```

Comment: What is your locale when sorting?

Comment: I have different kinds of locale. Not restricted to one kind.

Comment: Sorting order depends on locale.

Comment: Is there a way to handle different locale?

Comment: I don't understand the code: you get a list of data from somewhere (WebDriver), sort a copy of it and then verify that they are both the same. Why? What is the goal?

Comment: You can use [`Collator.getInstance(Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale)) to get a `Collator` for a specific locale. A `Collator` is a `Comparator`.

Comment: Goal is I am trying to validate the sorting works on the portal or not. I click to start the sorting, the read the value from the list of web elements then use the same values to sort by self and then verify both to make sure sort works.

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Yes there is.  You may want to study the internationalization section of the Oracle Java tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html to understand Locales better.

Comment: Why do you call `Collections.sort(sortedList);` for ascending order, but `Collections.sort(obtainedList,Collections.reverseOrder());` for descending? Of course, the latter doesn’t modify `sortedList` at all when you pass `obtainedList` to it. Besides that, to make a copy of a list, just use `ArrayList<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(obtainedList);`. And when you want to have case insensitive order, you have to say that explicitly. Use `sortedList.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` for ascending and `sortedList.sort(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed());` for descending order.